# Laravel post input as array with defferent key is not validating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am posting `search` parameter like as below

```
search[value]: something text // copied from debugger
```

In my controller I need to check if search.value is empty or not

```
if(empty($request->input('search.value')){

}else{

}
```

But always else statement is going to true, which means if-statement does not works.

When I debug it

```
array:2 [
  "value" => null
  "regex" => "false"
]
```

Can someone kindly let me know how can I check it properly I would appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: Please display your view code because `search.value` not supported

Comment: This naming syntax generates array variables in PHP, so this should probably be `$request->input('search')['value']` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use the filled method:

```
if ($request->filled('search.value')) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a array from input, So you can do something like below,

```
$search = $request->input('search');
if($search['value']){

}else{

}
```

Comment: Can you dd($request->all()) ? and share the result.

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code

```
if(empty($request->input('search.value'))){
    return 123;
}else{
    return 456;
}
```

Just complete your bracket in if condition.